# How to extract data from a partially corrupt multi-part rar archive?

Tags: windows-7, zip, archiving, winrar, file-corruption

I downloaded a video that's 11 parts the other day. Today I tried to extract it but it tells me that part04 is corrupt. So I checked "keep broken files", but of course it only gave me the beginning of the video. So I'm wondering if it's possible to extract it starting at part05. If that can't be done, does anyone know a way to possibly fix the corrupt archive? Thank you.

Note: I re-downloaded part04 and it still doesn't work. It's the right size too, so I know there were no downloading errors.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you have the first part of the archive, it will be possible to at least partially extract the files. In WinRAR, use the advanced extraction (`Extract to...`) and tick the `Keep broken files` checkbox. When the errors come up, before closing the error box, navigate to the destination of the extraction and copy your partial file out.

Depending on the video format, it may still be playable. For example, VLC will attempt to repair some files and can sometimes still play them without repairing. Windows Media Player also sometimes plays broken files, though you may have to manually seek past the break. There are also other free/commercial video repair programs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to **Repair archive** option of the WinRAR to repair *part4* and start to extract from 1st archive.
2. If it doesn't help, you can start to extract from part5. Simply, get rid of first 4 parts (move to another location etc.) before extract. But, if there is only one file to extract, this will fail. You can extract only files stored in part5 and subsequent parts, not first 4 parts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, after repairing it still says the file is corrupt. And it's just one file. So I guess all hope is lost. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is archived with no actual compression (“store” mode) then it is possible to access its contents with a hexadecimal editor, and copy-paste each segment manually (minus the header / footer).

It is possible that a single byte is corrupted, in which case the video file should be read by most media players, with only a glitch at some point.