# If I lose a DVD that contains a zip file part, will I need to make the whole collection again?

Tags: dvd, compression, zip

I have been backing up my data to some DVD-DLs, and I still have the original data.

But when I burned it to disc, I compressed it in a zip file to make parts of it. Now one of the disc accidentally broke.

Will I have to throw away all the discs that contains the zip parts because they are basically useless without the one missing? Is it possible to only write one disc and skip burning other discs? If I can re-zip the file divide them into similar size will it be possible?

Comment: If this is `.zip` file (not sure for other formats), you can still use it. If you try to `unzip`, it will extract all files of available parts only and will report error for file which were there in missing part. You can compare it with files available and can archive (as separate `zip`) only those files (from original source) which were there in missing part. This works even if any middle part is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't throw the discs away!

### Recreate the missing disc

If you have the original zip or (unchanged) data, you can recreate the missing disc, following the procedure you did before. If you are missing the fourth disc, simply burn `data.zip.004`, for example.

### Even if not, the discs still contain partial data

If you are missing one part of the archive, that part will be missing but you can still extract from the others:

> As long as you have the first part of the archive, it will be possible to at least partially extract the files.

*(from [a similar answer, albeit about multipart rar files](https://superuser.com/a/389272), by Bob)*

### Avoid the problem in future by including error correction data

You can use tools which add [extra data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_code) to create a correctable archive (eg '[Parchive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive)'), which includes sufficient redundant data to re-create missing information, at the cost of larger file size (in your case, more discs).

> Parchive (a portmanteau of parity archive, and formally known as Parity Volume Set Specification[1]) is an erasure code system that produces par files for checksum verification of data integrity, with the capability to perform data recovery operations that can repair or regenerate corrupted or missing data.

Comment: how would i create the zip.004. If i do the same procedure as before. will it create the same file as zip.004 that was lost? i will try to re compress it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the zip/multi-volume packaging used and whether you made use of any recovery options prior to the packaging.

E.g. WinRAR has a "Recovery Record" which, I guess, works similarly to data parity that if one or more of the split volume elements is unreadable it can use this as a method to rebuild broken/missing parts.

Personally I try not to use split packaging because of this... I'd much rather buy a suitably sized disk to fit all my data and then another to backup to... storage is failry cheap nowadays so it doesn't make sense to complicate processes.